# Getting element in array that matched text index query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose, full-text-indexing

I have the following Schema set up on mongoose

```
{
    _id:
    store:
    offers:[{
        name:
        price:
    }]
}
```

I decided to indexed offers.name as follows

```
uniSchema.index({'offers.name':'text'});
```

and now I'm trying to do searches on that index

```
Stores.find({$text:{$search:VALUE}}, callback);
```

But this way whenever there's a hit on the search the whole store is listed, and I'm unable to figure out from which offer the match came from.

Is there a way to do this with indexes on mongoose? Figuring out which array element matched the query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible with a `$text` index.

With a straight query you can use a projection to do the same:

```
> db.array_find.find({ "offers.name": "firstname"},{"offers.$" : 1} )
```

But the text query doesn't reference the array directly so `offers.name` is not able to be used in the projection.

```
> db.array_find.find({ $text: { $search: "firstname"} },{"offers.$" : 1} )
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Positional projection 'offer.$' does not match the query document.",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

The problem with attempting any type of post processing of the array from a result document is your not going to be using mongo's text indexing but some approximation of it.

You may need a different data structure

```
_id:
store: 2
offer: 
  name: this is a single offer
  price: 4

_id:
store: 2
offer:
  name: this is the next offer
  price: 5
```

Comment: Maybe if I use a subdocument approach it would work, but then it's relational. It's useless to use Mongo on that. :(